# Is there a way to install zune player application on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-server-2012, zune

I know it is not supported on Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 yet but still is there any kind of workaround to install it on a Windows Server 2012 machine?

**Edit:** It's a 64-bit installation.

**Edit 2:** [image: Here is the screenshot of the error:]

Comment: have you tried the Win 7 compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, I have but it still doesn't work.

Comment: which error message do you get?

Comment: What makes you think this application not supported on Windows 8 because it is?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Please see my second edit. I have now attached the error I am getting. I have also come to understand it is indeed possible to install it on Windows 8 after installing .Net Framwwork 3.5 but not yet on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I solved this problem of mine, I felt obliged that I should list out the ways this problem, *i.e. installing Zune Media Player on Windows Server 2012*, can be fixed.

First of all, you can go [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/zune/forum/zune_install-pc/how-to-install-zune-software-on-windows-server/94cd82a3-c721-49fb-854b-6ce3858e0bad?msgId=04d67643-3e11-4787-b638-323b34bf25a3) at Microsoft Answers and see the following (question+answer):

***Method 1***

> 1. In **Server Manager**'s **Add Roles Features Wizard** check if **.Netframework
>      3.5** **Features** and **Desktop Experience** are installed. It should be!
> 2. Download full **ZunePackage.exe** from official download page (version
>      4.8 is approx. 270 Mb)
> 3. Unzip **ZunePackage.exe** as an archive file (by **7-zip** or other tool) to specific folder (let's name it **Zune**).
> 4. In **Zune\x64\packages** subfolder find **zune-x64.msi**, **zunewmdu-x64.msi**
>      (and maybe **zune-***.msi** for your native language) .
> 5. Run **zunewmdu-x64.msi** to install **Windows Phone 7** devices updater.
> 6. Run **zune-x64.msi** to install core components of Zune software.
> 7. (optional) Run **zune-***.msi** to obtain your native language in Zune. Note, it
>      should be server's GUI language too.

***Method 2***

As answered by [Dieter Bäumler](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/zune/forum/zune_install-pc/how-to-install-zune-software-on-windows-server/94cd82a3-c721-49fb-854b-6ce3858e0bad?msgId=04d67643-3e11-4787-b638-323b34bf25a3&tm=1363685459752) at the same page of Microsoft Answers:

> The **zunewmdu-x64.msi** and **zune-x64.msi** (as mentioned above) should be installed as administrator using Command Line as follows:

```
msiexec /i <package>
```

***Method 3***

If both of the above methods don't work, ***as in my case***, right-click **zune-x64.msi** and go to its properties and set its compatibility option as shown below and then run it:
[image] 

Of all these methods, **Method 1 *(Only 1st Step)* and Method 3** worked for me together.